# Sorting Object Arrays when the key has different names

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to understand how to sort a JavaScript object array by the integer values. However, I am not having much luck after looking at a number of previous solutions online. I suspect this might be due to the way I have built my array, but due to lack of knowledge, I am unsure of the reason.

When I have looked for guidance, a lot of the examples show a common key name which is accessed, however, I would prefer to use different key properties as shown below.

I have a JavaScript object array that looks as follows:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Avobath_Count: "5"}
1: {DragonsEgg_Count: "3"}
2: {Intergalactic_Count: "2"}
3: {Twilight_Count: "9"}
4: {SexBomb_Count: "6"}
5: {TheExperimenter_Count: "6"}
6: {TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"}
7: {Butterball_Count: "3"}
8: {MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"}
9: {ThinkPink_Count: "2"}
```

I have tried to use:

```
keysSorted = Object.keys(presentationOrder).sort(function(a,b){return presentationOrder[a]-presentationOrder[b]}).map(key => presentationOrder[key]);
```

However, this has not sorted my array from high to low based on the values.

I would like to get my array to appear as follows:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {Twilight_Count: "9"}
1: {SexBomb_Count: "6"}
2: {TheExperimenter_Count: "6"}
3: {Avobath_Count: "5"}
4: {TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"}
5: {Butterball_Count: "3"}
6: {DragonsEgg_Count: "3"}
7: {Intergalactic_Count: "2"}
8: {ThinkPink_Count: "2"}
9: {MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"}
```

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do all your objects always have only one key?

Comment: Do all of the keys end with "_Count"?

Comment: Create another property with the same name on all your objects and sort by that. Or try this: Object.keys(obj)[0]

Comment: Your desired output doesn't appear to be sorted by value - have I mis-understood what you want?  [9, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 0]

Comment: A fiddle, pen or executable (copy-pastable) example is really helpfull here

Comment: @MikeBrockington sorry for the confusion, I have been staring at this too long and messed up whilst typing it out! I have added an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to extract the values of the object and compare it to `sort`

```js
let arr = [
  {Avobath_Count: "5"},
  {DragonsEgg_Count: "3"},
  {Intergalactic_Count: "2"},
  {Twilight_Count: "9"},
  {SexBomb_Count: "6"},
  {TheExperimenter_Count: "6"},
  {TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"},
  {Butterball_Count: "3"},
  {MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"},
  {ThinkPink_Count: "2"},
]

arr.sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the `objects` inside the array have only one pair of `key-value` then you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) inside the `sort()` method:

```js
let input = [
  {Avobath_Count: "5"},
  {DragonsEgg_Count: "3"},
  {Intergalactic_Count: "2"},
  {Twilight_Count: "9"},
  {SexBomb_Count: "6"},
  {TheExperimenter_Count: "6"},
  {TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"},
  {Butterball_Count: "3"},
  {MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"},
  {ThinkPink_Count: "2"}
];

input.sort((a ,b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);
console.log(input);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, alternatively you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) too:

```js
let input = [
  {Avobath_Count: "5"},
  {DragonsEgg_Count: "3"},
  {Intergalactic_Count: "2"},
  {Twilight_Count: "9"},
  {SexBomb_Count: "6"},
  {TheExperimenter_Count: "6"},
  {TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"},
  {Butterball_Count: "3"},
  {MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"},
  {ThinkPink_Count: "2"}
];

input.sort((a, b) => Object.entries(b)[0][1] - Object.entries(a)[0][1]);
console.log(input);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you did `Object.keys`, you retrieved the field names and lost access to their counts. Instead, get their counts using `Object.values()[0]` inside the sort handler.

```js
let input = [
  {Avobath_Count: "5"},
  {DragonsEgg_Count: "3"},
  {Intergalactic_Count: "2"},
  {Twilight_Count: "9"},
  {SexBomb_Count: "6"},
  {TheExperimenter_Count: "6"},
  {TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"},
  {Butterball_Count: "3"},
  {MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"},
  {ThinkPink_Count: "2"},
];

let output = input.sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I suspect this might be due to the way I have built my array, but due to lack of knowledge, I am unsure of the reason.*

If you have control over the way your array is built, then I'd suggest a change in the object structure:

```js
let input = [ 
  { "Name": "Avobath", "Count": "5" },
  { "Name": "DragonsEgg", "Count": "3" },
  { "Name": "Intergalactic", "Count": "2" },
  { "Name": "Twilight", "Count": "9" },
  { "Name": "SexBomb", "Count": "6" },
  { "Name": "TheExperimenter", "Count": "6" },
  { "Name": "TurtleImmersion", "Count": "5" },
  { "Name": "Butterball", "Count": "3" },
  { "Name": "MarshmallowWorld", "Count": "0" },
  { "Name": "ThinkPink", "Count": "2" } 
  ];

input.sort((a, b) => +b.Count - +a.Count);
console.log(input);
```

This doesn't only make it easier for you to sort by count, but makes your code cleaner (and clearer), too.

Let's say that maybe you'd like to sort your array alphabetically:

```js
let input = [ 
  { "Name": "Avobath", "Count": "5" },
  { "Name": "DragonsEgg", "Count": "3" },
  { "Name": "Intergalactic", "Count": "2" },
  { "Name": "Twilight", "Count": "9" },
  { "Name": "SexBomb", "Count": "6" },
  { "Name": "TheExperimenter", "Count": "6" },
  { "Name": "TurtleImmersion", "Count": "5" },
  { "Name": "Butterball", "Count": "3" },
  { "Name": "MarshmallowWorld", "Count": "0" },
  { "Name": "ThinkPink", "Count": "2" } 
  ];

input.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
console.log(input);
```

For this to work in your original structure, you'd have to do this:

```
input.sort((a ,b) => Object.keys(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.keys(b)[0]));
```

Which doesn't look very pretty, in my opinion.

Let's also say that now you've decided to add another property to your objects. Then you discover that your sorting isn't working anymore:

```js
let input = [
  {AnotherProp: "13", Avobath_Count: "5"},
  {AnotherProp: "-1", DragonsEgg_Count: "3"},
  {AnotherProp: "7", Intergalactic_Count: "2"},
  {AnotherProp: "5", Twilight_Count: "9"},
  {AnotherProp: "11", SexBomb_Count: "6"},
  {AnotherProp: "2", TheExperimenter_Count: "6"},
  {AnotherProp: "0", TurtleImmersion_Count: "5"},
  {AnotherProp: "4", Butterball_Count: "3"},
  {AnotherProp: "6", MarshmallowWorld_Count: "0"},
  {AnotherProp: "1", ThinkPink_Count: "2"}
];

input.sort((a ,b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);
console.log(input);
```

This would never happen if you kept `Name` and `Count` as separated properties, as suggested before. I could keep mentioning other examples where your current object structure would make things difficult to you (and to others trying to read your code), but I guess this is sufficient by now.